# Integrate Latex (Overleaf) and Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm writing my master's thesis in Overleaf, and I want to write my "Results" chapter in rmarkdown. I want to know how can I integrate these two. I know that I can include

```
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
```

in rmarkdown to get the Latex file and upload it in overleaf, but that is not a desirable integration. Does anyone know a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Knitr